# Open infinite window of Preferences Pane in Cocoa app when using segue

Tags: macos, cocoa, segue, nsmenuitem

I want to open a preference pane in my Cocoa app when an user taps the `Preferences...` menu or typing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>. So I connected from the preferences menu item to the window controller in storyboard as a `show` segue.

However, while this opens the preference pane when an user taps `Preferences...`, if the user taps the menu item again before closing the pane, another pane is going to be launched and displayed on the screen.

I want to have only one preference pane in my screen but how can I do that? I want to set it up only on storyboard and avoid coding that makes the nest of nest of boring menu items...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to prevent the windows from being launched multiple times, you select `Single` from the Window Controller's *Attribute Inspector* on Storyboard.

[image]

The default value is `Multiple`, causing the infinite windows to be launched.

Alternatively, if you want to use the code, here is something I will do in `AppDelegate.swift`.

```
extension AppDelegate: NSSeguePerforming {
    func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if identifier == OpenPreferencesIdentifier {
            let windows = NSApp.windows
            for window in windows {
                if window.windowController?.className == MyPreferencesWindowController.className() {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Also do NOT forget to set the appropriate segue identifier on Storyboard.